# Integrating Octopus and powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment, powershell-3.0, schedule, octopus-deploy

Using `list-deployment` & `list-latestdeployments` to get the information about all deployments done in Octopus deployment tool through Powershell scripting.
Is there any way to get the information regarding the future deployments which are scheduled in Octopus through Powershell. There is no direct command exist in Octo command line.

Comment: You should use REST API calls, in this case, if you need a wider range of functionality

Comment: https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api